# How to mount a directory in Linux

Tags: linux

We have tried to mount a directory in Linux as `mount /home/User/backup` but getting an error

> Only root can do that

Comment: So use root or sudo. BTW this is on topic for the Unix & Linux SE moreso than SO

Answer (score 3):

You need to elevate the privileges...

Try `sudo mount /home/User/backup`

Comment: When we try with sudo mount /home/User/backup getting an error "mount: can't find /home/user/backup in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab"

Answer (score 1):

The general mount command syntax to mount a directory Linux,

```
sudo mount source_dir destination_dir
```

**sudo** is a program for Unix-like computer operating systems that allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default the superuser.

Answer (score -1):

Mounting and unmounting filesystems usually requires root authority. If you are logged in as an ordinary user, you will either use su - to switch to root or sudo.

user able to access the "mount" command try to below url.

https://superuser.com/questions/677423/debian-allow-user-to-be-root-only-for-specific-commands